# What does it mean to change the color channel?

Tags: image, colors, color-space, color-channel

Does it mean to control the combination between an image and a color overlay applied to it depending on the color space used (RGB, RGBA, CMYK, Lab, Grayscale, HSL, HSLA)? Or does it mean to change the color layer used in combination with other layers to form the final image? (if so, what could be changed in what regard?).

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, you forgot to add the context from where you picked that phrase.

Comment: @mmgp what phrase are you talking about?

Comment: The one that defines your question.

Comment: It's not from a written source I'm afraid.

Comment: Then it makes no sense at all I'm afraid.

Comment: @mmgp You shouldn't edit without a reason. It relates to image-processing and color-channel (I don't know why you event deleted this one). Image processing represents the means of modifying an input image from the pixel/color perspective. Please tell me what's not making any sense to you? What I mean (to detail it some more) is that what is color channel control dependent on? Adding some more color on each channel from a color space or what else?

Comment: The whole question makes no sense. I know what image-processing is about, and that is exactly why the tag should be removed here -- your question is meaningless and, as it stands, has no image-processing task attached to it. The color-channel tag should be eliminated because it turns out your question is the only one with it in the whole site. This is another indication that you have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22000/discussion-between-andrew-g-h-and-mmgp)

Comment: Please accept that this question is as related to image-processing as reading user input is a natural language processing. Be nice, accept that the tag must be removed.

Answer (score 0):

`RGB` are abbreviations for three color channels (red, green and blue).  They represent specific frequencies of light.  Inside each color channel is a range of intensity and a level of saturation. This model of colors is commonly taught in school and is how most people understand colors and mixing them.  A different way to represent colors is `HSL` which stands for Hue, Saturation and Level.  Here the Hue is the frequency of the color, while the Saturation can be like the contrast level, and Level is the amount of black.  HSL (A stands for Alpha or transparency) is actually a much more programmer centric way of working with color (although most programmers seem to learn the RGB Hex values for colors).  There is a great website called [Mothereffing HSL](http://mothereffinghsl.com/) which lets you play with HSL values to better understand them.  CMYK is for pigments (which mix differently than light) and is found on printers.  Same basic idea as RGB just with Cyan Magenta Yellow and Black.  Now because light and pigments don't mix the same way there is a lot of work devoted to converting one color system to another (so you can see on your screen what will eventually come out of your printer).  These systems are not perfectly aligned however so the goal is to get acceptability close.

[image: Here is a comparison between RGB and CYMK]

All of these colors when presented on a graph are called the [color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space).

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question.

Comment: Ok, so controlling the channels means to control the amount of individual color space colors (red, green or blue for RGB; cyan, magneta, yellow and black for CMYK; and Hue, saturation and Value for HLS). But do they have initial values dependent of the image used or does it mean adding more color to the current image? Please give more details, thanks.

Comment: Each pixel in your image can be represented by a combination of the 3 or 4 values that ech system represents. To add or take from one of these values is what is meant by adjusting that channel.